# htaccess rewriterule condition needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup my URL rewrites to check for a certain template and if it doesnt exist use a default one

So if I have a URL:
http://www.mysite.co.uk/feed/

I want it to check if feed.php exists and use that if it does, but if it doesn't to use page.php?page=feed instead

This is what I currently have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ page.php?page=$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It works fine if feed.php exists, but when it doesn't it defaults straight to my custom 404.php and bypasses the second rewrite rule

I know it I need some kind of RewriteCondition but I dont know enough about it and cant find a pertinent example

Any help would be much appreciated! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/
RewriteCond /%1.php !-f
RewriteRule .* /page.php?page=%1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add check to see if the file does not exist

```
# serve file if exists
RewriteCond ^([^/.]+).php !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

That should be the first rule just after `RewriteEngine On`